# To find the greatest integer value in hadoop (using java programming)

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I have started working in hadoop recently and I have just learned some basic theoretical knowledge about it. I am trying to solve a task where the input shall be be given in a text file, for example input.txt (1 10 37 5 4 98 100 etc)

I need to find the largest integer in the given inputs (ie. integer type). I am trying to pass the inputs in the arraylist, so that I can compare the first integer with the rest of all the integers (using for-loop).

The program should read the input file say some random numbers 100 20 40 90 70, then the output should display as 100. I have just tried to modify the code with wordcount example in map and reduce function. But since I am new to start coding in hadoop I could not figure it out where I am wrong.

1)Is it possible to find the solution in this way? if yes, I could not create an arraylist here in hadoop and need some tips :-)

2)Can we print only 'key' instead of key-value pairs? If so please help me. I tried to code in reduce function for not printing it but I am getting some errors.

Please guide me with some tips by which I can move forward. Thank you

Comment: Could you be a little more specific as to exactly what the input and expected output is? "Greatest value" of what? I also noticed you tagged this as word-count; how does that relate to this? And lastly, [what have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: The program should read the input file say some random numbers 100 20 40 90 70, then the output should display as 100. I have just tried to modify the code with wordcount example in map and reduce function. But since I am new to start coding in hadoop I could not figure it out where I am wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the Hadoop Java API and write the following functions:

```
Map: Identity function

Reduce (or Combine): (K, List<V>) -> (K, max(List<V>))
```

Regarding your comment, there are no `ArrayLists` in MapReduce, those would not fit in memory. A list of values is passed as an iterator, and objects are often reused to save memory - so you can not rely on their contents to remain the same.

Mapper API: http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.1.1/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/Mapper.html

For your mapper you could write the following function, or just use the pre-implemented `IdentityMapper`.

```
public void map(K key, V val, Context context)
throws IOException {
    context.collect(key, val);
}
```

Reducer API: http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.1.1/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/Reducer.html

Your reduce function would be (assuming `V implements Comparable<V>`), and for brevity, we'll say that values contains at least one item:

```
public void reduce(K key, Iterator<V> values, Context context)
throws IOException {
    V max = values.next();
    while( values.hasNext() ) {
        V current = values.next();
        if( current.compareTo(max) > 0 )
            max = current;
    }
    context.collect(key, max);
}
```

Comment: What is L here? Is it a key?

Comment: Sorry, typo. It was supposed to be `K`.

Comment: Okay. Can you tell me how the input is passed as an array in hadoop?

Comment: Thank you so much for your kind reply. I will work on it and i will let you know. Thank you.